# The complex cosine is injective in the range $0<Re(z)<\pi/2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that complex cosine $Cosz$ is injective in the range $0<Re(z)<\pi/2$. Show that the image of this range is right half-plane $Re(z)>0$ minus the semi-line $x+0i$, $x \geq 1$.

I tried use $cosz=cosx.coshy-isenx.senhy$, where $z=x+iy$, I know that $cosx$ and $senhy$ are strictly increasing and $cosx$ is strictly decreasing in $0<Re(z)<\pi/2$ and $coshy$ is increasing in $[0,+\infty)$. But this not help. Then tried use $Cosz=Cosw$, but I could not find $z=w$. 
can someone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that

$$\cos z=\cos w\iff\frac12\left(e^{iz}+e^{-iz}\right)=\frac12\left(e^{iw}+e^{-iw}\right)\iff$$

$$\frac{e^{2iz}+1}{e^{iz}}=\frac{e^{2iw}+1}{e^{iw}}\iff e^{i(2z+w)}+e^{iw}=e^{i(2w+z)}+e^{iz}\iff$$

$$ e^{i(z+w)}\left(e^{iz}-e^{iw}\right)=e^{iz}-e^{iw}$$

Finish now the argument...

Comment: I arrive $ i(z+w)=0$, but I wanted to find that $z=w$. Here I must use $0<Re(z)<\pi/2$?

Comment: @RicardoFreire I can't see how you arrived to that. The last equation is possible only if $\;e^{iz}=e^{iw}\;$ , which cannot be because of the condition on their real parts (remember: for real $\;x\;,\;\;e^{ix}=1\iff x=2k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$), or else $\;e^{i(z+w)}=1\; $, which again cannot be...

Comment: In fact I applied the logarithm to both members. I was able to conclude. Thank you very much

Comment: What two members? And beware of the *complex* logarithm! It is a bad beast light years away from being well behaved as its real cousin...

Comment: I fixed that. Thank you. Now I can not show the image set, can it help?

Comment: Observe that for any $\;z=x+iy\in\Bbb C\;$, we have $$\;2\cos z=e^{-y+ix}+e^{y-ix}=e^{-y}(\cos x+i\sin x)+e^y(\cos x-i\sin x)=$$$$=\cos x\cosh y-i\sin x\sinh y$$ The real part of the above is always positive (why? Check the images of $\;\cos x\,,\,\,\cosh y\;,\;\;x\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$)